# How to make multiple url on the embed? (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

**How to make each line of `video_title` become hyperlink for a url? (`url1`, `url2`, `url3`, ... `url10`)**

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=(
                                             "`1.` " + video_title1 + "\n\n"
                                             "`2.` " + video_title2 + "\n\n"
                                             "`3.` " + video_title3 + "\n\n"
                                             "`4.` " + video_title4 + "\n\n"
                                             "`5.` " + video_title5 + "\n\n"
                                             "`6.` " + video_title6 + "\n\n"
                                             "`7.` " + video_title7 + "\n\n"
                                             "`8.` " + video_title8 + "\n\n"
                                             "`9.` " + video_title9 + "\n\n"
                                             "`10.` " + video_title10 + "\n"
                                             ), color=9699539)

embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.author.name}",
                 icon_url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/26/c8/03/26c8038be8ac9ac7594bb23a03c5c8be.jpg")
await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lP4H.png

My bot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k48Ni.png

Comment: Do you mean hyperlinks?

Comment: Yes, hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [fields](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.fields) of an embed, via using [add_field](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.add_field) with the `name` of the field, the `value` of the field, and whether it is line per line ( `inline=False`). Also I recommend that you look into this website : https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/ to see how the embed could look like

Comment: Yes, but how to place hyperlinks in these embed fields?
I edited the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed, using: [video title](url hidden)

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=(
                                             f"`1.` [{video_title1}]({url1})\n\n"
                                             f"`2.` [{video_title2}]({url2})\n\n"
                                             f"`3.` [{video_title3}]({url3})\n\n"
                                             f"`4.` [{video_title4}]({url4})\n\n"
                                             f"`5.` [{video_title5}]({url5})\n\n"
                                             f"`6.` [{video_title6}]({url6})\n\n"
                                             f"`7.` [{video_title7}]({url7})\n\n"
                                             f"`8.` [{video_title8}]({url8})\n\n"
                                             f"`9.` [{video_title9}]({url9})\n\n"
                                             f"`10.` [{video_title10}]({url10})\n"
                                             ), color=9699539)
```

Print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGsjK.png